# How to make changes in the ListView fetching data directly from Server?

Tags: android, listview

I have made a live score app. I want to make changes after every match, update matches played, won lost etc. How to make this changes?

Comment: Post Your code in which u try for all of things

Comment: I have not made yet..bt can i know the concept fetching data to android app from server that is written in php

Comment: This is far too broad, Mohammed. One key learning for software engineers is how to ask good questions (anywhere on the web, not just here). Either this is so broad that someone would have to ask you a great deal about your app in order to see if their ideas would work, or they can give a very general answer, and they end up doing all your work for you.

Comment: So, give your readers much more detail, by editing your question, and then make a genuine and honest and determined effort to try it yourself first. Then let us know how you get on, and what _specific_ part you are stuck on.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you want to update the score on the list items in ListView. I believe you are fetching data from the web-service and storing the scores in list and then displaying them in your ListView. I can recommend the following:

1. Make request to the web-service in a definite interval say every one minute and update your list then call notifyDataSetChanged() for your ListView adapter.
2. Implement Firebase Cloud Messaging on Server and well as in your application and push notifications to your app for new score/match data available on the server. For FCM implementation in android See this : [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client)